# Still getting 'Symbol' is undefined' error even after adding babel-polyfill in my webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/#usage-in-browser

I did not understand the lines on the documentation page under:

> Usage in Browser heading

can someone help me with what else is required:

Below are my code snippets:

I'm using storybook as a boilerplate:

```
webpack.config.js file:

entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
    paths.appIndexJs
]

index.js file:

import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
```

Is there some other files also where I need to add `babel-polyfill` related code.

```js
require('babel-polyfill');
var path = require('path');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
var InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
var WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
var getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
var paths = require('./paths');
var publicPath = '/';
var publicUrl = '';
var env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    entry: ['babel-polyfill',
        require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
        require.resolve('./polyfills'),
        paths.appIndexJs
    ],
    output: {
        path: paths.appBuild,
        pathinfo: true,
        filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
        publicPath: publicPath
    },
    resolve: {
        fallback: paths.nodePaths,
        extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx', ''],
        alias: {
            'react-native': 'react-native-web'
        }
    },
    module: {
        // First, run the linter.
        // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
        preLoaders: [{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            loader: 'eslint',
            include: paths.appSrc,
        }],
        loaders: [{
                exclude: [/\.html$/, /\.(js|jsx)$/, /\.css$/, /\.json$/],
                loader: 'url',
                query: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
                }
            },
            // Process JS with Babel.
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                include: paths.appSrc,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    cacheDirectory: true
                }
            }, {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style!css?importLoaders=1!postcss'
            }, {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json'
            }
        ]
    },
    // We use PostCSS for autoprefixing only.
    postcss: function() {
        return [
            autoprefixer({
                browsers: ['>1%', 'last 4 versions', 'Firefox ESR', 'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                ]
            }),
        ];
    },
    plugins: [
        new InterpolateHtmlPlugin({
            PUBLIC_URL: publicUrl
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: true,
            template: paths.appHtml,
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(env),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
        new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules)
    ],
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get this code into your browser.

1 - Include the babel-polyfill module in the webpack bundle

2 - Load it as an external script in your html

**Webpack - adding bundle dependencies with entry arrays**

Put an array as the entry point to make the babel-polyfill module available to your bundle as an export.

With webpack.config.js, add babel-polyfill to your entry array.

The webpack docs explain how an entry array is handled:

> What happens when you pass an array to entry? Passing an array of file
>   paths to the entry property creates what is known as a "multi-main
>   entry". This is useful when you would like to inject multiple
>   dependent files together and graph their dependencies into one
>   "chunk".

Webpack.config.js

```
require("babel-polyfill");

var config = {
   devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
   entry: {
    main: [
      // configuration for babel6
      ['babel-polyfill', './src/js/main.js']
    ]
  },
 }
```

**Alternative to Webpack - load babel-polyfill as an external script in the browser html**

The alternative to using webpack would mean including the module as an external script in your html. It will then be available to code in the browser but the webpack bundle won't be directly aware of it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.22.0/polyfill.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have done the way you mentioned as well as the way is mentioned in the documentation but still error persists in console of IE.


My code is below:

webconfig.js file:
require("babel-polyfill");

module.exports = {
devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  entry: [ 'babel-polyfill', paths.appIndexJs]


and also in index.js file I have written

import 'babel-polyfill';


but still error persist.

Comment: in the console of IE 11 browser. app works properly but the error is in console.

Comment: SCRIPT5009: 'Symbol' is undefined, 
runtime.js (537,9)

Comment: Can you update your question and add the code from your webpack config?

Comment: Make sure every element in the entry array is a string